# Lossless import of full OpenStreetMap planet dump into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, imposm

I would like to import a full OpenStreetMap planet dump as PBF into a PostGIS tables.

With tools like osm2pgsql or imposm3, configuration files are neccessary. Unfortunately, it is not possible to taking into account all possible attributes.

Is there a tool or way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For osm2pgsql, you can use the `--hstore` parameter.

From the [doc](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/usage.md#hstore):

> --hstore or -k adds any tags not already in a conventional column to a hstore column. With the standard stylesheet this would result in tags
>   like highway appearing in a conventional column while tags not in the
>   style like name:en or lanes:forward would appear only in the hstore
>   column.